# SPARQL Subqueries and DELETE

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to delete a specific triple related to a series of similar things. So, where we have...

```
someURI a our:thing;
 our:name "literal".
someOtherURI a our:thing;
 our:name "literal".
...n
```

I want to specifically remove all `someURI our:name "literal"` triples and leave the things defined.

I know I can do this via `DELETE DATA`, but that requires I know all URIs first, which is too many steps in itself.

I'm struggling a bit with `DELETE WHERE`, but I assume the answer is something like...

```
DELETE{ ?uri our:name ?literal }
WHERE{ ?uri a our:thing. }
```

Firstly, is my `DELETE WHERE` sound?

Secondly, I'm wondering if it's possible to nest a `SELECT` query within a `DELETE DATA`? So...

```
DELETE DATA{ 
 ?uri our:name ?literal
 {
   SELECT ?uri
   WHERE {?uri a our:thing.}
 }
}
```

Specifically, would the subquery provide the ground triple (the URI to replace the `?uri` variable, or would the no variable rule for `DELETE DATA` throw the error first? It seems obvious, but I've been wondering and can't test it out on my triplestore. I'm using OWLIM-SE.

Comment: Why do you say you can't test it out on your triplestore? Pretty sure OWLIM-SE supports SPARQL 1.1 update, unless you are using a _very_ old version...

Comment: The repository is part of a content life cycle. I don't like toying with things, and the second question was really just something I've always wondered. While we do have a redundant dev instance, I try to keep the data aligned with production. As deviation stacks, my tests get more and more meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Firstly, is my `DELETE WHERE` sound?

Almost, but not quite. A `DELETE` clause can not contain any variables that are not bound in the `WHERE` clause (the variable `?literal`, in your case). So you need to modify it slightly, like so:

```
DELETE { 
  ?uri our:name ?literal .
}
WHERE { 
  ?uri a our:thing; 
       our:name ?literal . 
}
```

> Secondly, I'm wondering if it's possible to nest a `SELECT` query within
>   a `DELETE DATA`?

That is not possible. A `DELETE DATA` operation can *only* contain fixed RDF triples - no variables and certainly no subqueries.

However, you *can* use a nested `SELECT` in a `DELETE WHERE` operation if you want. So the following is legal:

```
DELETE { 
  ?uri our:name ?literal .
}
WHERE { 
  { SELECT ?uri ?literal 
    WHERE { ?uri a our:thing; 
                 our:name ?literal . 
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't really give you any advantage to do this though, in your particular case: this update expresses exactly the same thing as the first one, just in a more roundabout way.

Comment: Thank you, Jeen, for the confirmation.